# Force download of PDF file on the same PHP page

Tags: php, pdf

I have a PHP file that includes a link to a .pdf file that opens in a new tab - this essentially simply opens the page which downloads the PDF to the user's downloads folder immediately - the new tab doesn't remain open in the browser. This is all working well.

I'm now trying to change it so that the php page will load and do the download of the pdf in the one page, without the user having to click another link to download the pdf file.

Here's the structure with the 2 page setup - the `viewReport.php` page has a link like this:

```
$downloadLink = 'downloadFile.php?fileName='.$fileName.'&path='.$url;
$displayLink = 'This Report was successfully created. <a href="'.$downloadLink.'" class="alert-link" target="_blank">Click here</a> to view the PDF.';
```

The `downloadFile.php` page has the following:

```
$fileName = $_GET['fileName']; 
 header('Content-type: application/force-download'); 
 header('Content-Disposition:filename="'.$fileName.'"');
 echo $fm->getContainerData($_GET['path']);
```

which works to immediately download the PDF. I've now changed the `viewReport.php` page to include this:

```
 $downloadLink = 'downloadFile.php?fileName='.$fileName.'&path='.$url;
 header('Content-type: application/force-download'); 
 header('Content-Disposition:filename="'.$fileName.'"');
 echo $fm->getContainerData($url);
```

When this page loads it does download a PDF file that it cannot be opened and is about 1/3 the size of the one that is generated with the 2 page version, so obviously not a valid PDF file. Also the `viewReport.php` page appears to stop loading once it processes this line hat downloads the pdf file:

```
 echo $fm->getContainerData($url);
```

and then appears to go back to the previous page.

This is my first time trying to do this in a single page so not sure if this can even be done this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do both actions of rendering a new page for the user to view while simultaneously triggering an automatic file download *with a single request*.

The problem is that both of those actions require specific headers being sent in order to deliver their payloads correclty. Obviously you're seeing the headers you need to set to trigger the file download, but the delivery of a web page also requires specific headers which are normally set for you in the background. And the headers for delivering a web page for viewing vs. a file download are not compatible with each other - you can only send one or the other in a single response.

With all that said, there are probably other workarounds possible using javascript and ajax. But ultimately it all comes down to sending separate requests in order to receive two distinct sets of headers required for the two scenarios.